# How to apply equivalences in the Limit?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Actually, I have the following expression $a1$:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
$Assumptions = {c > 0, h > 0};
a1 = (c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4 h^2])/(4 h Sqrt[c^2 + h^2]) // FullSimplify
```

Both $c$ and $h$ are positive real numbers. However, I want to show by Mathematica that once $c>>h$, i.e., $c$ is much more than $h$, then $a1$ could be simplified in the limit case to the following expression which is easier to handle:

```
a2 = 1/(2 h) (1 + h^2/(2 c^2)) // FullSimplify
```

But I cannot incorporate the equivalency $c>>h$ into the command Limit[].

I will be thankful if someone puts some comments to overcome it.

Comment: `Simplify[ Limit[
  Simplify[(c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4 h^2])/(4 h Sqrt[c^2 + h^2]) /. c -> h/z], z -> 0], h > 0]`

Comment: Or `Simplify[#, h > 0] & //@ 
 Limit[(c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4 h^2])/(4 h Sqrt[c^2 + h^2]) /. c -> h/z, 
  z -> 0]`

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. We should obtain $a2$ by imposing the condition $c>>h$ on $a1$. Is there a way to reach $a2$ from $a1$?

Comment: You can expand in a "small parameter" to desired order: `Normal@Series[a1 /. h -> \[Epsilon] c, {\[Epsilon], 0, 2}] /. \[Epsilon] -> h/c // FullSimplify`.